# php foreach loop help

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, foreach

I have a foreach loop that builds me a product page basically it out puts my products in rows of 3.

See the code:

```
foreach ($product_sets as $product)
{
    $currentRow = ceil($currentItem / 3);
    $currentColumn = $currentItem - (($currentRow - 1) * 3);
    if ($number_of_blanks == 2) :
        if (($number_of_rows > 1 && $currentRow == ($number_of_rows - 1) && $currentColumn == 2) || ($number_of_rows == 1 && $currentColumn == 1)) :
    ?>
            <li><img src="<?php echo site_url('assets/img/blocks/guarantee.png'); ?>" alt="5 Year Guarantee" width="242" height="156"></li>
    <?php
            $currentItem++;
        endif;
    endif;
    ?>
    <li class="<?php if($currentItem % 3 == 0) echo 'endHomeBlock';?>">
        <?php $this->load->view('blocks/product_small', array('product' => $product)); ?>
    </li>
    <?php
        $currentItem++;

    }
```

What I am wanting be able to do is place an image (A point of sale) at the end of the first row, and the randomly through the other rows, but maintaining 3 items (including image a point of sale) on a row.  I have the image paths in an array called images which looks similar to this,

```
$images = array(
  'iamge1.png',
  'image2.png,
  'image3.png,
  'image4.png,
);
```

How can I achieve this? I have been scrathing around for a few hours now :(

Comment: So you will always have three items per row?  But randomly want to add images in the results (randomly except for the first row)?

Comment: yep you summised what I want perfectly!

Comment: Probably it's nothing related, but your example array above, only the first item is correctly quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I don't have much time in writing you the full code, but the following should work:

```
<ul>
    <li><?php
        foreach($items as $i=>$item){
            // ...write item...
            if(($i % 3)==0 && $i!=0){ // if multiple of 3 and not the first time..
                ?></li><li><?php
            }
        }
    ?></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I would do is create a hashtable of your images and at what points in the table you want to display them.  The key of the table would be the index and the value would be the image name.

Assuming `$currentItem` is zero-based, the first key you would have would be `2` for the third item in the first row.

Then in your loop, check and see if `$currentItem` is in the hashtable.  If it is, print the image and increment `$currentItem` (and recalculate row and column) and then print `$product`.  If it is not in the hashtable, just print `$product` like normal.

Comment: could you give me an example of a hashtable, I have never heard that term before, or maybe even an example of the loop? even if it pseudo code

Comment: @sea_1987 hashtable == associative array